# How to add an empty line at the end of these commands?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, merge, fasta

I am in a situation where I have so many fastq files that I want to convert to fasta.
Since they belong to the same sample, I would like to merge the fasta files to get a single file.

I tried running these two commands:

```
sed -n '1~4s/^@/>/p;2~4p' INFILE.fastq > OUTFILE.fasta

cat infile.fq | awk '{if(NR%4==1) {printf(">%s\n",substr($0,2));} else if(NR%4==2) print;}' > file.fa
```

And the output files is correctly a fasta file.

However I get a problem in the next step. When I merge files with this command:

```
cat $1 >> final.fasta
```

The final file apparently looks correct. But when I run makeblastdb it gives me the following error:

```
FASTA-Reader: Ignoring invalid residues at position(s): On line 512: 1040-1043, 1046-1048, 1050-1051, 1053, 1055-1058, 1060-1061, 1063, 1066-1069, 1071-1076
```

Looking at what's on that line I found that a file header was put at the end of the previous file sequence. And it turns out like this:

```
GGCTTAAACAGCATT>e45dcf63-78cf-4769-96b7-bf645c130323
```

**So how can I add a blank line to the end of the file within the scripts that convert fastq to fasta?**

So that when I merge they are placed on top of each other correctly and not at the end of the sequence of the previous file.

Comment: Try `cat $1 <(echo) >> final.fasta`, don't judge me, first thing that popped up on my mind!

Comment: [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Comment: It sounds like you are using DOS text files, which use line "endings" as a line *separator*, not a line *terminator*. `cat` is designed to work with POSIX text files, where *every* line (including the last) is followed by a linefeed. The `awk` pipeline works because `awk` (also a POSIX tool) correctly outputs a linefeed following every line of text. `cat` does not add anything to what it reads from its input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So how can I add a blank line to the end of the file within the
> scripts that convert fastq to fasta?

I would use GNU `sed` following replace

```
cat $1 >> final.fasta
```

using

```
sed '$a\\n' $1 >> final.fasta
```

Explanation: meaning of expression for `sed` is at last line (`$`) append newline (`\n`) - this action is undertaken before default one of printing. If you prefer GNU `AWK` then you might same behavior following way

```
awk '{print}END{print ""}' $1 >> final.fasta
```

Note: I was unable to test any of solution as you doesnot provide enough information to this. I assume above line is somewhere inside loop and `$1` is always name of file existing in current working directory.

Comment: @ Daweo : _  **ANY** and **EVERY** `awk` can do that piece of `awk` code - why did you intentionally specify `gawk` ?

Answer (score 0):

if the only thing you need is extra blank line, and the input files are within `1.5 GB` in size, then just directly do :

```
awk NF=NF RS='^$' FS='\n' OFS='\n'
```

Should work for `mawk 1/2`, `gawk`, and `nawk`, maybe others as well. This works despite appearing not to do anything special is that the extra `\n` comes from `ORS`.